# Is it possible to dynamically create delegate to the method currying some parameters (and do it without expression's compile, and DynamicInvoke)?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, delegates

Is it possible to dynamically create delegate to the method currying some parameters (and do it without expression's compile, and DynamicInvoke)?

With DynamicInvoke invoke currying would look like

```
var methodInfo = typeof(MyTools).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod(nameof(MyTools.MyMethod));
var delegateType = typeof(Func<,,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(int), typeof(int), typeof(int));
var @delegate = methodInfo.CreateDelegate(delegateType);
var i2 = 1;
var func = (i1) => { return (int)(@delegate.DynamicInvoke(i1, i2)); };
```

With expression's lambda compile it is also possible but I skip it there.

In my vision methodInfo.CreateDelegate that I search require some additional parameters that would accept i2 , do the currying, and return delegate of type Func<,>.

P.S. The price of lambda compilation is a run-time overhead that we have because of JIT_MethodAccessCheck. When with currying operation I search it should be possible to create deleage without JIT_MethodAccessCheck.

Answer (score 1):

You can curry any function by creating a series of overrides for methods with various argument counts:

```
public static class Prelude
{
    public static Func<T1, Func<T2, R>> curry<T1, T2, R>(Func<T1, T2, R> f) =>
        (T1 a) => (T2 b) => f(a, b);

    public static Func<T1, Func<T2, Func<T3, R>>> curry<T1, T2, T3, R>(Func<T1, T2, T3, R> f) =>
        (T1 a) => (T2 b) => (T3 c) => f(a, b, c);

    public static Func<T1, Func<T2, Func<T3, Func<T4, R>>>> curry<T1, T2, T3, T4, R>(Func<T1, T2, T3, T4, R> f) =>
        (T1 a) => (T2 b) => (T3 c) => (T4 d) => f(a, b, c, d);

    // ... etc ...
}
```

Next I'll define a placeholder function for what I think your `MyTools.MyMethod` looks like.

```
public static class MyTools
{
    public static C MyMethod<A, B, C>(A a, B b) => default(C);
}
```

Then to test it out:

```
using static Prelude;

public class CurryTest
{
    public void Test()
    {
        var f = curry<int, int, int>(MyTools.MyMethod<int, int, int>);

        var c = f(1)(2);
    }
}
```

My [functional language extensions library](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext) has all the overrides you'll need for [currying](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/blob/master/LanguageExt.Core/Prelude/Prelude_Curry.cs) and [partial application](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/blob/master/LanguageExt.Core/Prelude/Prelude_PartialApplication.cs)

Comment: I construct the same delegate, but construct it  dynamically. Imagine you have T1, T2, T3, T4 in Type[3] array and need to do the same.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question.  Why are you creating it dynamically?  It's almost certainly slower using reflection to do this.  The only way to curry a function like this would be with nested `Func`, and so you must build a lambda.